# How to profile Golang Web App Server

Tags: go, web-applications, profiling, benchmarking

I have a web app server written using [Go](http://golang.org) ([httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter)/[gokil](https://gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil)), when I test it using `siege -b -t10s -c255`, it shows something like this (best score):

```
POST API (read only query to database, cache query result to RAM)
Transaction rate:            4251.38 trans/sec (local without proxy)
Transaction rate:            2082.11 trans/sec (local with proxy)
Transaction rate:            1806.63 trans/sec (test server)  

GET Realistic  (static file request, multiple URL)
Transaction rate:            4417.75 trans/sec (local without proxy)
Transaction rate:            1419.58 trans/sec (local with proxy)
Transaction rate:             234.73 trans/sec (test server)
Transaction Rate:              40.50 trans/sec (other external site that use gokil)

GET One static file  (getting /js/jquery.js)
Transaction rate:            4166.83 trans/sec (local without proxy)
Transaction rate:            2531.79 trans/sec (local with proxy)
Transaction rate:              31.39 trans/sec (test server)
Transaction rate:              20.95 trans/sec (other external site that use gokil)

For comparison, hello world 
Transaction rate:           13838.83 trans/sec (plain Go https://play.golang.org/p/y8rJ4ZkclD )
Transaction rate:            5420.79 trans/sec (local without proxy https://gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/tree/master/_example )
Transaction rate:            2701.12 trans/sec (local with proxy)
```

The specs for `local` is i7-4772HQ, Samsung 850 SSD.

Proxy I use is [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/). Database I use is PostgreSQL and Redis for storing sessions. `test server` is on the same network with gigabit connectivity.

The question is, how to measure timing of each request: which function/line of code that causes the bottleneck? Because I look at other [benchmark](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r13&hw=ph&test=db) Go can achieve `70k` to `171k` rps.

I've tried this [blog](https://medium.com/@tjholowaychuk/profiling-golang-851db2d9ae24#.h839kusa1), but it shows:

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/_example
$ go build
$ go tool pprof —text ./test 
parsing profile: unrecognized profile format
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, found a way from [this blog post](https://medium.com/@tjholowaychuk/profiling-golang-851db2d9ae24#.h839kusa1), I misread the example.

1. Just add `defer profile.Start(profile.CPUProfile).Stop()` on start of main function.
2. Import/Go get `github.com/pkg/profile`
3. Build and run the program, benchmark it, exit the program, at the end of the line it would show something like this:

> ```
> 2016/11/24 18:41:24 profile: caught interrupt, stopping profiles
> 2016/11/24 18:41:24 profile: cpu profiling disabled, /tmp/profile627033993/cpu.pprof
> ```

4. Run the command pprof command `go tool pprof -text /tmp/profile627033993/cpu.pprof`

It would show something like this:

```
$ go tool pprof -text /tmp/profile627033993/cpu.pprof
12.89s of 16.31s total (79.03%)
Dropped 386 nodes (cum <= 0.08s)
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 7.26s 44.51% 44.51%      7.40s 45.37%  syscall.Syscall
 0.42s  2.58% 47.09%      0.62s  3.80%  runtime.scanobject
 0.38s  2.33% 49.42%      1.09s  6.68%  runtime.mallocgc
 0.32s  1.96% 51.38%      0.32s  1.96%  runtime.memmove
 0.27s  1.66% 53.03%      0.27s  1.66%  runtime.futex
 0.25s  1.53% 54.57%      1.21s  7.42%  runtime.gentraceback
 0.21s  1.29% 55.86%      0.59s  3.62%  runtime.pcvalue
 0.19s  1.16% 57.02%      0.19s  1.16%  runtime.usleep
 0.18s  1.10% 58.12%      0.18s  1.10%  runtime.readvarint
 0.15s  0.92% 59.04%      0.15s  0.92%  runtime.heapBitsForObject
 0.15s  0.92% 59.96%      0.15s  0.92%  runtime.heapBitsSetType
 0.14s  0.86% 60.82%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime._ExternalCode
 0.14s  0.86% 61.68%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.epollctl
 0.13s   0.8% 62.48%      0.13s   0.8%  runtime.rtsigprocmask
 0.12s  0.74% 63.21%      0.16s  0.98%  runtime.deferreturn
 0.12s  0.74% 63.95%      0.17s  1.04%  runtime.greyobject
 0.12s  0.74% 64.68%      0.16s  0.98%  syscall.Syscall6
 0.11s  0.67% 65.36%      0.40s  2.45%  runtime.adjustframe
 0.11s  0.67% 66.03%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.adjustpointers
 0.11s  0.67% 66.71%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.memclr
 0.11s  0.67% 67.38%      0.29s  1.78%  runtime.step
 0.10s  0.61% 68.00%      1.53s  9.38%  runtime.systemstack
 0.07s  0.43% 68.42%      0.21s  1.29%  runtime.mapassign1
 0.07s  0.43% 68.85%      0.25s  1.53%  runtime.rawstring
 0.06s  0.37% 69.22%      0.17s  1.04%  runtime.scanblock
 0.06s  0.37% 69.59%      0.17s  1.04%  time.Time.AppendFormat
 0.05s  0.31% 69.90%      0.12s  0.74%  runtime.casgstatus
 0.05s  0.31% 70.20%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.lock
 0.05s  0.31% 70.51%      0.56s  3.43%  runtime.newobject
 0.05s  0.31% 70.82%      0.18s  1.10%  runtime.tracebackdefers
 0.04s  0.25% 71.06%      0.75s  4.60%  bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice
 0.04s  0.25% 71.31%      0.32s  1.96%  fmt.(*pp).doPrintf
 0.04s  0.25% 71.55%      7.22s 44.27%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.LoadSession
 0.04s  0.25% 71.80%      0.32s  1.96%  runtime.scanframeworker
 0.04s  0.25% 72.04%      0.12s  0.74%  runtime.typedmemmove
 0.03s  0.18% 72.23%      0.25s  1.53%  fmt.(*pp).printArg
 0.03s  0.18% 72.41%      0.47s  2.88%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*stringFormatter).Format
 0.03s  0.18% 72.59%      0.67s  4.11%  net.(*netFD).Read
 0.03s  0.18% 72.78%     12.43s 76.21%  net/http.(*conn).serve
 0.03s  0.18% 72.96%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan
 0.03s  0.18% 73.15%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.deferproc.func1
 0.03s  0.18% 73.33%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.exitsyscall
 0.03s  0.18% 73.51%      0.09s  0.55%  runtime.makemap
 0.03s  0.18% 73.70%      0.72s  4.41%  runtime.markroot
 0.03s  0.18% 73.88%      0.09s  0.55%  runtime.runqgrab
 0.02s  0.12% 74.00%      0.65s  3.99%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).readLine
 0.02s  0.12% 74.13%      0.78s  4.78%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).readReply
 0.02s  0.12% 74.25%      0.09s  0.55%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).writeCommand
 0.02s  0.12% 74.37%      0.39s  2.39%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/Z.(*TemplateChain).Render
 0.02s  0.12% 74.49%      1.28s  7.85%  main.AuthFilter
 0.02s  0.12% 74.62%      0.32s  1.96%  net.(*netFD).accept
 0.02s  0.12% 74.74%      4.74s 29.06%  net.dialSingle
 0.02s  0.12% 74.86%      0.11s  0.67%  net/http.(*connReader).Read
 0.02s  0.12% 74.98%      0.66s  4.05%  net/http.(*response).finishRequest
 0.02s  0.12% 75.11%      0.49s  3.00%  net/http.readRequest
 0.02s  0.12% 75.23%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.SetFinalizer
 0.02s  0.12% 75.35%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.concatstrings
 0.02s  0.12% 75.48%      0.68s  4.17%  runtime.findrunnable
 0.02s  0.12% 75.60%      0.27s  1.66%  runtime.makeslice
 0.02s  0.12% 75.72%      0.90s  5.52%  runtime.morestack
 0.02s  0.12% 75.84%      0.12s  0.74%  runtime.newarray
 0.02s  0.12% 75.97%      0.32s  1.96%  runtime.pcdatavalue
 0.02s  0.12% 76.09%      0.27s  1.66%  runtime.rawstringtmp
 0.02s  0.12% 76.21%      0.78s  4.78%  runtime.schedule
 0.02s  0.12% 76.33%      0.57s  3.49%  syscall.read
 0.01s 0.061% 76.39%      0.71s  4.35%  bufio.(*Reader).fill
 0.01s 0.061% 76.46%      1.82s 11.16%  bufio.(*Writer).flush
 0.01s 0.061% 76.52%      0.34s  2.08%  fmt.Sprintf
 0.01s 0.061% 76.58%      5.19s 31.82%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).get
 0.01s 0.061% 76.64%      0.25s  1.53%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).put
 0.01s 0.061% 76.70%      2.14s 13.12%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).Do
 0.01s 0.061% 76.76%      0.31s  1.90%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*pooledConnection).Close
 0.01s 0.061% 76.82%      1.96s 12.02%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*pooledConnection).Do
 0.01s 0.061% 76.89%      0.75s  4.60%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).Notice
 0.01s 0.061% 76.95%      0.74s  4.54%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*backendFormatter).Log
 0.01s 0.061% 77.01%      0.42s  2.58%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Context).Finish
 0.01s 0.061% 77.07%      0.42s  2.58%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Context).Render
 0.01s 0.061% 77.13%     10.37s 63.58%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Engine).ServeHTTP
 0.01s 0.061% 77.19%      0.10s  0.61%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Session).parseIpAddr
 0.01s 0.061% 77.25%      2.57s 15.76%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.Logger
 0.01s 0.061% 77.31%      0.37s  2.27%  net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP
 0.01s 0.061% 77.38%      0.68s  4.17%  net.(*conn).Read
 0.01s 0.061% 77.44%      1.62s  9.93%  net.(*conn).Write
 0.01s 0.061% 77.50%      4.62s 28.33%  net.(*netFD).connect
 0.01s 0.061% 77.56%      0.10s  0.61%  net.(*pollDesc).init
 0.01s 0.061% 77.62%      4.71s 28.88%  net.doDialTCP
 0.01s 0.061% 77.68%      0.09s  0.55%  net.runtime_pollClose
 0.01s 0.061% 77.74%      0.18s  1.10%  net/http.(*chunkWriter).writeHeader
 0.01s 0.061% 77.81%     10.38s 63.64%  net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
 0.01s 0.061% 77.87%      0.43s  2.64%  net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept
 0.01s 0.061% 77.93%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.adjustdefers
 0.01s 0.061% 77.99%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.callers.func1
 0.01s 0.061% 78.05%      0.23s  1.41%  runtime.convT2E
 0.01s 0.061% 78.11%      0.12s  0.74%  runtime.deferproc
 0.01s 0.061% 78.17%      0.29s  1.78%  runtime.funcspdelta
 0.01s 0.061% 78.23%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.futexsleep
 0.01s 0.061% 78.30%      0.24s  1.47%  runtime.gcAssistAlloc
 0.01s 0.061% 78.36%      1.18s  7.23%  runtime.gcDrain
 0.01s 0.061% 78.42%      0.20s  1.23%  runtime.gcDrainN
 0.01s 0.061% 78.48%      0.09s  0.55%  runtime.gcMarkTermination
 0.01s 0.061% 78.54%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.netpoll
 0.01s 0.061% 78.60%      0.88s  5.40%  runtime.newstack
 0.01s 0.061% 78.66%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.notesleep
 0.01s 0.061% 78.72%      0.64s  3.92%  runtime.park_m
 0.01s 0.061% 78.79%      0.10s  0.61%  runtime.runqsteal
 0.01s 0.061% 78.85%      0.59s  3.62%  runtime.scang
 0.01s 0.061% 78.91%      0.53s  3.25%  runtime.scanstack
 0.01s 0.061% 78.97%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.startm
 0.01s 0.061% 79.03%      1.67s 10.24%  syscall.Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.12s  0.74%  bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine
     0     0% 79.03%      1.82s 11.16%  bufio.(*Writer).Flush
     0     0% 79.03%      0.09s  0.55%  bytes.(*Buffer).Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.14s  0.86%  fmt.Fprintf
     0     0% 79.03%      0.17s  1.04%  github.com/fatih/color.(*Color).SprintfFunc.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.17s  1.04%  github.com/fatih/color.BlueString
     0     0% 79.03%      0.17s  1.04%  github.com/fatih/color.printString
     0     0% 79.03%      5.21s 31.94%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).Get
     0     0% 79.03%      0.17s  1.04%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).Close
     0     0% 79.03%      4.91s 30.10%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*xDialer).Dial
     0     0% 79.03%      4.93s 30.23%  github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.Dial
     0     0% 79.03%      0.73s  4.48%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*LogBackend).Log
     0     0% 79.03%      0.74s  4.54%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*Logger).log
     0     0% 79.03%      0.49s  3.00%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*Record).Formatted
     0     0% 79.03%      0.74s  4.54%  github.com/op/go-logging.(*moduleLeveled).Log
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Engine).StartServer
     0     0% 79.03%      0.30s  1.84%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Session).Save
     0     0% 79.03%      0.73s  4.48%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.(*Session).Touch
     0     0% 79.03%      5.16s 31.64%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.InitSession.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      1.32s  8.09%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.Recover
     0     0% 79.03%      0.73s  4.48%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.Session.ShouldRenew
     0     0% 79.03%      0.09s  0.55%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.hashCookie
     0     0% 79.03%      0.24s  1.47%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/W.newSession
     0     0% 79.03%      0.27s  1.66%  gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil/Z.(*TemplateChain).Reload
     0     0% 79.03%      0.24s  1.47%  log.(*Logger).Output
     0     0% 79.03%      0.52s  3.19%  main.Test
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  main.main
     0     0% 79.03%      4.81s 29.49%  net.(*Dialer).Dial
     0     0% 79.03%      4.81s 29.49%  net.(*Dialer).DialContext
     0     0% 79.03%      0.36s  2.21%  net.(*TCPListener).accept
     0     0% 79.03%      0.58s  3.56%  net.(*conn).Close
     0     0% 79.03%      0.58s  3.56%  net.(*netFD).Close
     0     0% 79.03%      1.61s  9.87%  net.(*netFD).Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.57s  3.49%  net.(*netFD).decref
     0     0% 79.03%      0.57s  3.49%  net.(*netFD).destroy
     0     0% 79.03%      4.65s 28.51%  net.(*netFD).dial
     0     0% 79.03%      0.10s  0.61%  net.(*netFD).init
     0     0% 79.03%      0.09s  0.55%  net.(*pollDesc).close
     0     0% 79.03%      4.81s 29.49%  net.Dial
     0     0% 79.03%      0.11s  0.67%  net.accept
     0     0% 79.03%      4.74s 29.06%  net.dialSerial
     0     0% 79.03%      4.71s 28.88%  net.dialTCP
     0     0% 79.03%      4.69s 28.76%  net.internetSocket
     0     0% 79.03%      4.69s 28.76%  net.socket
     0     0% 79.03%      0.26s  1.59%  net/http.(*Cookie).String
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  net/http.(*Server).Serve
     0     0% 79.03%      0.18s  1.10%  net/http.(*chunkWriter).Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.47s  2.88%  net/http.(*conn).close
     0     0% 79.03%      0.61s  3.74%  net/http.(*conn).readRequest
     0     0% 79.03%      0.47s  2.88%  net/http.(*conn).serve.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.10s  0.61%  net/http.(*response).WriteHeader
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  net/http.ListenAndServe
     0     0% 79.03%      0.26s  1.59%  net/http.SetCookie
     0     0% 79.03%      0.40s  2.45%  net/http.checkConnErrorWriter.Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.16s  0.98%  net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadLine
     0     0% 79.03%      0.16s  0.98%  net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadMIMEHeader
     0     0% 79.03%      0.12s  0.74%  net/textproto.(*Reader).readLineSlice
     0     0% 79.03%      0.20s  1.23%  os.(*File).Write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.20s  1.23%  os.(*File).write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.22s  1.35%  os.Stat
     0     0% 79.03%      0.17s  1.04%  runtime.(*mcache).nextFree
     0     0% 79.03%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.(*mcache).nextFree.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.(*mcache).refill
     0     0% 79.03%      0.13s   0.8%  runtime.Caller
     0     0% 79.03%      0.30s  1.84%  runtime._System
     0     0% 79.03%      0.11s  0.67%  runtime.callers
     0     0% 79.03%      0.86s  5.27%  runtime.copystack
     0     0% 79.03%      0.14s  0.86%  runtime.futexwakeup
     0     0% 79.03%      0.20s  1.23%  runtime.gcAssistAlloc.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      1.07s  6.56%  runtime.gcBgMarkWorker
     0     0% 79.03%      0.09s  0.55%  runtime.gcMarkDone
     0     0% 79.03%      0.19s  1.16%  runtime.gchelper
     0     0% 79.03%        14s 85.84%  runtime.goexit
     0     0% 79.03%      0.16s  0.98%  runtime.goexit0
     0     0% 79.03%      0.46s  2.82%  runtime.main
     0     0% 79.03%      0.59s  3.62%  runtime.markroot.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.87s  5.33%  runtime.mcall
     0     0% 79.03%      0.13s   0.8%  runtime.minit
     0     0% 79.03%      0.26s  1.59%  runtime.mstart
     0     0% 79.03%      0.26s  1.59%  runtime.mstart1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.12s  0.74%  runtime.notewakeup
     0     0% 79.03%      0.32s  1.96%  runtime.scanstack.func1
     0     0% 79.03%      0.24s  1.47%  runtime.slicebytetostring
     0     0% 79.03%      0.35s  2.15%  runtime.stopm
     0     0% 79.03%      0.13s   0.8%  runtime.sysmon
     0     0% 79.03%      0.10s  0.61%  syscall.Accept4
     0     0% 79.03%      0.43s  2.64%  syscall.Close
     0     0% 79.03%      4.56s 27.96%  syscall.Connect
     0     0% 79.03%      0.57s  3.49%  syscall.Read
     0     0% 79.03%      0.21s  1.29%  syscall.Stat
     0     0% 79.03%      0.10s  0.61%  syscall.accept4
     0     0% 79.03%      4.56s 27.96%  syscall.connect
     0     0% 79.03%      1.66s 10.18%  syscall.write
     0     0% 79.03%      0.18s  1.10%  time.Time.Format
```

The dot version http://pastie.org/10969011 you can generate the graph call on http://www.webgraphviz.com/